# Aggregate concatenated numbers with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a CSV imported to Google Spreadsheet with a column with values like `20230110_30 ::: 20240112_40`. This format encodes that a user in this row has made two donations: 30EUR on 10 Jan, 2023 and 40EUR on 12 Jan, 2024. Of course, it can be one donation, two donations, three donations, etc.

How can I calculate the following aggregate values for every row in my spreadsheet:

- total amount of donations (in the example above: 70)
- total number of donations (in the example above: 2)
- the last year of donation (in the example above: 2024)

I've tried using `ArrayFormula` and `regexextract`, but `regexextract(, "_(\d+)")` only extracts the first occurrence, but I need all of them to aggregate. Maybe a way forward could be doing some string replaces and pushing the resulting expression into some `eval` function if it exists in Spreadsheets?

I control the format of this column (except the separator of `:::`), so if needed I can do tweaks.

I can easily do this in Python, but struggle with Google Spreadsheets formulas. Is it possible with formulas? If not, is it possible to write formulas using Python or some other fully-fledged programming language and stay in the Google Spreadsheet environment?

Grateful for any help!

---

I've tried making AppScript:

```js
function number_of_donations(s) {
  if(Array.isArray(s))
    return s.map(number_of_donations);
  else
      return s.split(' ::: ').length;
}
```

This worked and I can implement the other functionality using AppScript. Is it possible to place this code directly into the spreadsheet without a separate AppScript project?

But I still wonder if it's possible to use some clever native Spreadsheet formulas/functions to implement the functionality above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a string in the format `20230110_30`, we can use the following regular expression to extract `2023` and `30`:

```cpp
REGEXEXTRACT(string,"(....).+_(.+)")
```

If `string` is composed of substrings separated by `:::`, `string` becomes the following array of strings:

```cpp
TRIM(TOCOL(SPLIT(string,":")))
```

So the `REGEXEXTRACT` becomes:

```cpp
REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(TOCOL(SPLIT(string,":"))),"(....).+_(.+)")
```

We can then use `QUERY` to select the `max`, `count` and `sum`.

```cpp
=INDEX(
  QUERY(
    --REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(TOCOL(SPLIT(A2,":"))),"(....).+_(.+)"),
    "select max(Col1), count(Col1), sum(Col2)"),2)
```

[image]

If we want to apply this to the whole column, we can use [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en):

```cpp
=MAP(A2:A,
   LAMBDA(str,IF(str="",,
     INDEX(
       QUERY(
         --REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(TOCOL(SPLIT(str,":"))),"(....).+_(.+)"),
         "select max(Col1), count(Col1), sum(Col2)"),2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Your idea computes the aggregates per a given row, but I need to compute them automatically for an entire column. And if I found correctly, `QUERY` cannot be used inside `ARRAYFORMULA` to evaluate a formula over entire column :(

Comment: @VadimKantorov I just edited my answer. Please see if that helps.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you very much! What does `--` and `TOCOL` do?

Comment: Should we replace ":" with ":::"?

Comment: `--` converts a number string to a real number (ie `--"123"` becomes `123`. `TOCOL` turns a `NxM` array to a `(NxM)x1` array.

Comment: no, `SPLIT` by default ignores duplicates `SPLIT(str,":")` is equivalent to `SPLIT(str,":::")` which is equivalent to `SPLIT(str,"::::::::::::::::")`. This behavior can be changed by changing the other optional parameters.

Comment: It appears that I cannot sort rows by these newly calculated values, it seems that they have string datatype. How to make them number datatype? Is it possible to do in the formula?

Comment: They do not have string datatype, that's the purpose of `--`. The reason you cannot sort is because the array you are trying to sort is generated by a single formula. So you either have to use a formula for each row or wrap a SORT function around the formula.

Comment: Oh, that's a bummer - that was the whole point, to sort the donors by the number of transactions or the total amount :( It allowed me to sort but produced some bogus result, as if doesn't permute the whole rows according to the sort order.

Comment: Can I somehow burn in the computed values? I'm also pulling data into my sheet from the neighboring sheet via `={test!A1:G1000}` could this be also a problem? I'd like to just "burn in" the data pulled from the this `test` sheet and the calculated aggregates and work with them as if they were not calculated.

Comment: Please create a new post with your new question. Also provide a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this formula on the column (assuming it's column a), you'll get a cleaner data set.

```
=let(zSpliter," ::: ",zRng,A:A, zValues,ToCol(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(zsPliter,true,zrng),zSpliter)),
zDates,arrayformula(date(left(zValues,4),mid(zvalues,5,2),mid(zvalues,7,2))),
zAmounts,ARRAYFORMULA(mid(zValues,find("_",zValues)+1,99)+0),
fullData,hstack(zdates,zamounts),fullData)
```

This will get you two columns of dates/amounts. From there you could easily formulas, or even embed the above `<previousFormula>` into these:

- Total donations: `=rows(<previousFormula>)`
- Sum of donations: `=Sum(index(<previousFormula>,,2))`
- Max year: `Max(arrayformula(Year(Index(<previousFormula>,,1))))`

[See sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iJifOACSZQlvYpxqRsRRjBCiwR3JAeAwv82rM6oBQgA/edit#gid=2100307022)

Comment: I found a way to do some crazy regex abuses to get a column with formulas: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(I1:I, "\d{8}_", ""), " ::: ", "+"))`, but unfortunately it appears there is no way to evaluate such arithmetic/simple formulas using `ARRAYFORMULA` :(

I'll study your idea now!

Comment: Yea you're trying to do a literal string forced calculation which isn't necessary. Basically just join all of them with the same splitter (what text join does), then split, but all to one column... then split out by the underscore, and you have the two clean columns.

Comment: my date parameter was one digiit off. I just corrected it.