# Burn-in formula evaluated values in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a complex sheet in Google Spreadsheet:

- it pulls data from another sheet using `IMPORTRANGE`
- it contains complex formula applied to all rows using `ARRAYFORMULA`, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77809711/445810

However, if I apply filters/sorting, it does not work correctly, as if the formula gets re-evaluated on resorted rows.

Is it possible to burn-in the formula outputs (without manually copying the rows into another sheet, instead with some Sheet option or another formula like `IMPORTRANGE`), so that filtering and sorting works correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: see the comment under this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816792/filter-feature-doesnt-work-correctly-with-imported-data-in-google-sheets

Comment: can I burn in the all formula evaluations values somehow? (i know a way of manual copy-paste, but I don't know a programmatic way or a way without manually selecting the range). for instance, would it work if I create a new sheet and then use `IMPORTRANGE` to copy all generated values into a new sheet?

Comment: no that wouldn't work. Your only options are the options I mentioned in the link.